# App_GlobalResources vs web.config AppSettings

Tags: asp.net, iis, localization, resources, web-config

I'm using `App_LocalResouces` to create a multi-language website. and of course I'm using `App_GlobalResources` for global settings. But I don't get it how this `App_GlobalResources` is different from using `AppSetting` of web.config file?

Is there any performance advantages?

Is there any preference in using it than `AppSettings`?

Comment: App_GlobalResources is a folder that can hold multiple resource (resx) files where each file can contain strings in its own language. I use this folder for resource files like Strings.resx and Strings.fr.resx that I want to access from more than one page in a web application. I use App_LocalResources for files that  are each accessed by only one page like About.aspx.resx and About.aspx.fr.resx.

How would you use AppSetting as an alternative to App_GlobalResources?

Comment: @LonProsser well for localized resources I use the App_LocalResources but when I use something in general which is used in most pages I use App_GlobalResources where I think using keyvalue colletions of web.config will do the same

Comment: From MSDN: With App_GlobalResources you create a separate resource file for each language (for example, English and French) or for a language and culture (for example English [U.K.], English [U.S.]). Each localized resource file has the same key/value pairs; the only difference is that a localized resource file can contain fewer resources than the default resource file. The built-in language fallback process then handles loading the neutral or default resource. ASP.NET generates a strongly typed object that gives you a simple way to programmatically access global resources.

Comment: Those are advantages of using App_GlobalResources, compared to web.config.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.140%29.aspx